# Vue.js bind to DOM custom event with dots in name (like bootstrap events)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Using Vue 2.1.10

I can bind to DOM events with `v-on` directive. For example:

```
v-on:click
```

To bind to DOM click. 
But I can't figure how to bind to an event that has dots in the name. such as "show.bs.modal" from bootstrap.

Currently, I use a workaround binding in the `created` hook with Regular DOM Methods, but I really would like to use the declarative syntax for that. How can this be achieved? thanks

**EDIT:**
The question is about allowed syntax: how can I do something like:

```
Vue.component('comp',{
  template:'<div v-on:show.bs.modal="sunrise"></div',
  methods:{
    sunrise:function(e){

     }

   }
})
```

Comment: By dots you mean class names? '.class.name'

Comment: Can you throw up a jsfiddle on this demonstrating issue?

Comment: @Austio Not a "fiddle" question, a syntax question, see edit

Comment: See this: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/201 So, it would be something like: `v-on="show.bs.modal:..."` This is very old, I don't know if it still works, try it.

Answer (score 9):

I was facing the very same problem when working on old projects.

Luckily I found the answer here: [vue2 doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-on)

```html
<!-- object syntax (2.4.0+) -->
<button v-on="{ mousedown: doThis, mouseup: doThat }"></button>
```

This works on Bootstrap 5.1.1 with Vue 2.16.14:

```html
<div class="modal" v-on="{ 'hide.bs.modal': handleModalClose }">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think dots are not supported in `v-on` but you could create a custom directive to create an event listener for that event.

Not sure if there is something easier but something like in the demo below or this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/tgbvrLje/) should work.

The demo creates a new event with dots in name but that should also work with bootstrap events (not tested). Please let me know if it's not working with bootstrap and I'll have a look.

Unbinding only works if you're using `v-if`. If you're removing that element with Javascript directly. The event will still be there.

```js
var helloEvent = new Event('demo.event.hello');

document.addEventListener('demo.event.hello', function(e) {
  // this is just for testing event dispatching!
  console.log('main event listener');
}, false);

const bindCustomEvent = {
  getName: function(binding) {
    return binding.arg + '.' +
      Object.keys(binding.modifiers).map(key => key).join('.');
  },
  bind: function(el, binding, vnode) {
    const eventName = bindCustomEvent.getName(binding);

    console.log(el, eventName);
    document.addEventListener(eventName, binding.value);
  },
  unbind: function(el, binding) {
    const eventName = bindCustomEvent.getName(binding);
    console.log('unbinding', eventName);
    document.removeEventListener(eventName, binding.value);
  }
};

Vue.directive('bindCustomEvent', bindCustomEvent);

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      enabled: true,
      eventMsg: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sunrise: function(e) {
      console.log('received event');
      this.eventMsg = 'received event';
    },
    testEvent: function() {
      document.dispatchEvent(helloEvent);
    },
    toggle: function() {
      console.log('toggle', this.enabled);
      this.enabled = !this.enabled;

      if (!this.enabled) {
        this.eventMsg = '';
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-bind-custom-event:demo.event.hello="sunrise" v-if="enabled">
    Hello, {{eventMsg}}
  </div>

  <!--
  The following markup is not working
  <div v-on="demo.event.hello:sunrise" v-if="enabled">
    Hello, {{eventMsg}}
  </div>-->
  <button @click="testEvent()">
    Change
  </button>
  <button @click="toggle">
    <span v-if="enabled">disable custom event</span>
    <span v-else>enable custom event</span>
  </button>
</div>
```