# How to make bootstrap events work inside vue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, vue.js

I have a collapse that is inside of Vue container. now, the `hidden.bs.collapse` event of bootstrap doesn't work anymore.

I saw a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42513893/3779015) that needs to add a `ref=""` and include it in the `mounted` However the problem is that the condition inside of `hidden.bs.collapse` is automatically called even though the event is not yet called.

here's the code..

```
 methods: {
  test(){
      console.log('test function')
      $('#form_create')[0].reset();
      $(".alert").alert('close')
      $('input,textarea').removeClass('is-invalid')
    },
    test2(){
      console.log('1321');
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    $(this.$refs.createForm).on('hidden.bs.collapse', this.test());
    $(this.$refs.showForm).on('hidden.bs.collapse', this.test2());
  }
```

EDIT:

silly me. the 2nd parameter of the `on` shouldn't have `()`.

```
$(this.$refs.createForm).on('hidden.bs.collapse', this.test);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [bootstrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/)

Mixing Jquery and Vue.js is bad idea, because Vue.js uses Virtual DOM to perform changes, while Jquery uses only native DOM. Vue will not see Jquery changes event if it's works.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186149/vue-js-bind-to-dom-custom-event-with-dots-in-name-like-bootstrap-events).

Following that, you can do the following:

```
<create-form
    ...
    v-on="{'hidden.bs.collapse': test}"
>
    ...
</create-form>

...

<show-form
    ...
    v-on="{'hidden.bs.collapse': test2}"
>
    ...
</show-form>
```

I've found it nigh impossible to find an answer that "just works", with VueJS 3, the composition API, and TypeScript. This doesn't require either the Bootstrap or JQuery JS code, and it works according to VueJS deals with events.

Answer (score 0):

I'm about two years late to this party but for those that find this answer in the future, use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

The example code would become `$(document).on('hidden.bs.collapse', this.$refs.createForm, this.test);`

Here's another example of some code that wasn't working for me when the `.navbar-collapse` element was inside my vue app

```
$('.navbar-collapse').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', function() {
    $('html').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Here it works with event delegation:

```
$('#site-header').on('show.bs.collapse hide.bs.collapse', '.navbar-collapse', function() {
    $('html').toggleClass('open');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

<b-modal ref="someModal" @hide="doSometing">

you can use @hide in your modal
=> In your case

<b-modal ref="createForm" @hide="test()">
<b-modal ref="showForm" @hide="test2()">