# Alpine.js how to bind to DOM events with dots in the name

Tags: javascript, dom-events, alpine.js

Using Alpine.js version `2.7.3`, a component can [listen to DOM events](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#x-on) using `x-on:[event].[modifiers]`.

But what syntax is used to listen to event names that have dots, like bootstrap's `show.bs.modal`?

In Vue.js, this can be done by a custom directive (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186149/vue-js-bind-to-dom-custom-event-with-dots-in-name-like-bootstrap-events)), but I think custom directives can not be created in Alpine.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment since Alpine.js uses dots (`.`) to denote directive modifiers.

Answer (score 5):

You can target event names with dots by using the `.dot` modifier, which swaps any dashes for dots. For example, if you are going to target `show.bs.modal` you would do:

```
<div x-data>
    <div @show-bs-modal.dot="console.log($event)"></div>
</div>
```

Please see https://alpinejs.dev/directives/on#dot for details.

Answer (score 1):

A round about way is to listen to the custom event name on the document and then re-dispatch the event with a different name that Alpine.js can handle.

```
document.addEventListener('event.with.dots', function(evt, p1, ...) {
  // params and references to elements will depend on your requirement
  alpineComponentElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('eventwithnodots', {bubbles: true}))
})
```

```
<div x-data>
  <div x-on:eventwithnodots="$event"></div>
</div>
```