# Inline event handler in Vue.Js with dots in the name

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js, off-canvas-menu

I am building a SPA using the latest versions of Vue.js 3 and Bootstrap 5. In the main page I am using the Boostrap [Offcanvas](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/offcanvas) element with a code that is very similar to the one in the documentation.

The offcanvas definition looks like this

```
<div class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="categories">
    <div class="offcanvas-header">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas-body">
      ...
    </div>
 </div>
```

and this is the anchor that triggers it

```
<a data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" href="#categories" role="button">Categories</a>
```

I read in the Bootstrap documentation that the Offcanvas div fires some [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/offcanvas/#events) like `shown` and `hidden`, however the full name of these events is `shown.bs.offcanvas` and `hidden.bs.offcanvas`. Using vanilla Javascript I could do listen to those events like documented using `addEventListener` on the Offcanvas element, however I wanted to do things "the Vue way" using [Inline Handlers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#inline-handlers). But when I try to add

```
@show.bs.offcanvas="console.log('Showing');"
// or
v-on:show.bs.offcanvas="console.log('Showing');"
```

to the Offcanvas div I get the following errors

```
/Path/To/File/NavBar.vue
  48:123  error  'v-on' directives don't support the modifier 'bs'         vue/valid-v-on
  48:126  error  'v-on' directives don't support the modifier 'offcanvas'  vue/valid-v-on

✖ 2 problems (2 errors, 0 warnings)
```

So Vue sees the `.` and interprets `bs` and `offcanvas` [Event Modifiers](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/event-handling.html#event-modifiers).

Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem or knows how to specify *exact* even

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I did not do enough Googling around and the same question was already answered for Vue.js 2 [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186149/vue-js-bind-to-dom-custom-event-with-dots-in-name-like-bootstrap-events). I have self-flagged the post as duplicate just in case.

I can confirm that this works in Vue.js 3

```
v-on="{'show.bs.offcanvas': eventHandlerFunction }"
```